# Receiving the error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'DocumentClient')

Tags: node.js, promise, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have already imported the AWS sdk module, but after initializing the dynamoDB I'm getting the error: **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'DocumentClient')**

```
const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');
const AWS = AWSXRay.captureAWS(require('aws-sdk'));
const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

I am using **dynamoDB** object in a promise, not sure this is why it's not accessible. If I am relocating the initialization inside the function then I'm not getting this error

Comment: Did you try import it without x-ray?

Comment: Hello @LeeHannigan, tried that still getting the same error!

Comment: Where are you running the code from?? Which version of the JS SDK?

Comment: I am using the sdk version 2 and running it from cloud9 environment, the credentials are working correctly and the role is also configured correctly. If I do the dynamoDB initialization inside the function then it works but if I do it at the top of the file after initializing the sdk then it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try with the low level client? `const ddb = AWSXRay.captureAWSClient(new AWS.DynamoDB());`

Comment: I converted the syntax from promise to async/await and it looks like it's working, thanks for your assistance!